# Somar valores decimais no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Tenho a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT SUM('ValorTotal') AS Pagos,StatusCadastros FROM pe_cadastros WHERE StatusCadastros = 'A';
```

No campo `ValorTotal`, que está com o tipo `Decimal(7,2)` possui 02 valores:

> 1500.00 e 570.00

Só que mesmo tendo valores, o resultado está me retornando zero. Sinceramente não sei onde está o problema na *query*.

Já inclui o `GROUP BY ValorTotal`, mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tentando somar uma string não?

ValorTotal seria um campo, logo a query correta seria:

```
SELECT SUM(ValorTotal) as Pagos, StatusCadastros from pe_cadastros WHERE StatusCadastros = 'A';
```

Comment: Que falta de atenção minha. Me perdoem por isso!!

Comment: Ia fechar esse tópico, mas vou deixar em aberto para que outros colegas desatentos, assim como eu, possam ter uma solução. Muito obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 2):

Nomes de colunas devem ser escritas de forma direta, e não com aspas, assim você está mandando somar um texto, o que não faz o menor sentido. Então o correto seria:

```
SELECT SUM(ValorTotal) AS Pagos, StatusCadastros FROM pe_cadastros WHERE StatusCadastros = 'A';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Sum.sql).